# Does anyone have any experience with playing .midi files through midi->wav conversion or the like on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, midi

Does anyone have any experience with playing .midi files through midi->wav conversion or the like on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Iphone needs sounds to be in certain valid formats. Not sure if midi is supported directly but MacOSX comes with a command line tool to convert sounds.

I would run the following command on my sound files to convert them to a format I know works.

afconvert -v -f caff -d ima4 -c 1 filename.ext

and play either sound effects or ambient sound as follows

```
+ (void)PlaySFX:(NSString*)name
{
    NSUserDefaults* savedState = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 

    if ([savedState boolForKey:SFX])
    {
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory); 

        SystemSoundID sound;  
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"caf"]], &sound);  
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (sound);   
    }
}

+ (void)StartAmbientSound
{
    NSUserDefaults* savedState = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Volcano Erupting" ofType:@"caf"]] error: nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.volume = [savedState floatForKey:MUSICVOL];
    [player play];  
}
```